# FOXPRO: SMS using Curl to Post in a Adress with Headers, and use in FOXPRO

Tags: curl, sms, foxpro, shellexecute

I install a SMS Gateway in a phone with android.
If a use the CURL in command line, i can send the messages perfectly.
I try to transform in Foxpro way, and i have no luck.
Anyone can do a magic and help me?
Thanks in advance

Commandline:
curl -X POST http://192.168.10.57:8082 -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: f3e09bbd" -d "{"to": "+351987654321", "message": "Teste envio OK"}"

FoxPro:
_comando = 'curl -X POST http://192.168.10.57:8082 -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: f3e09bbd" -d "{"to": "987654321", "message": "Teste envio OK"}" -v'
msg(_comando)
ShellExecute(0,"post",_comando,"","",1)

Answer (score 0):

The FoxPro command is

```
Run curl -X POST http://192.168.10.57:8082 -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: f3e09bbd" -d "{"to": "+351987654321", "message": "Teste envio OK"}"
```